# kendo combobox giving text and values both same

Tags: asp.net-mvc, combobox, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using kendocombobox for MVC using cascade and below is my code...

```
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.maintDeptID)
                                 .DataTextField("MaintDeptdesc")
                                 .DataValueField("maintDeptID")
                                 .BindTo(ViewBag.MaintenanceDepartmentList)
   )
```

Second combobox as..

```
 @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.MaintSubDeptID)
       .DataTextField("MaintSubDeptDesc")
       .DataValueField("MaintSubDeptID")
       .DataSource(source =>
       {
       source.Read(read =>
               {
                   read.Action("GetCascadeMaintenanceSubDepartmentList", "Employee")
                   .Data("filterMaintenanceSubDepartment");
                })
               .ServerFiltering(true);
        })
        .Placeholder(EmployeeResource.PlaceholderMaintSubDeptment)
        .Enable(false)
        .AutoBind(false)
        .CascadeFrom("maintDeptID"))
```

and javascript code is as..

```
function filterMaintenanceSubDepartment() {
            return {
                maintDeptID: $("#maintDeptID").data("kendoDropDownList").value()
            };
        }
```

now when i am selecting second combobox it gives me the text as value like..
If I write..

```
$("#MaintSubDeptID").data("kendoComboBox").value()
$("#MaintSubDeptID").data("kendoComboBox").text()
```

both values give same result..

However I bound DataTextField as string and DataValueField as int..

please suggest..

In local system its working perfectly but on live it causes same issue...